# Simple Banking application in Spring boot, JPA, REST where balance can be transferred among predefined accounts and transaction history retrievable

Tags: java, rest, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I want to create a very simple banking application where (i) predefined accounts with a positive balance can send money (ii) requesting balance and a list of transactions can be found.

I have created API for those operations. All the operations are persisted into the database. I also wrote test cases to verify.

I always try to learn from different sources and use the best practices related to project structure and clean code. It would be great if somebody gives me suggestions and ideas about what improvement I can make on the codes.

Here is my project structure:

```
    ├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── forhadmethun
│   │   │           └── banking
│   │   │               ├── BankingApplication.java
│   │   │               ├── config
│   │   │               │   └── documentation
│   │   │               │       └── DocumentationConfig.java
│   │   │               ├── controller
│   │   │               │   ├── api
│   │   │               │   │   └── AccountController.java
│   │   │               │   └── request
│   │   │               │       ├── AccountStatementRequest.java
│   │   │               │       └── TransferBalanceRequest.java
│   │   │               ├── dto
│   │   │               │   ├── model
│   │   │               │   │   └── AccountStatement.java
│   │   │               │   └── response
│   │   │               │       ├── ResponseError.java
│   │   │               │       └── Response.java
│   │   │               ├── entity
│   │   │               │   ├── Account.java
│   │   │               │   └── Transaction.java
│   │   │               ├── repository
│   │   │               │   ├── AccountRepository.java
│   │   │               │   └── TransactionRepository.java
│   │   │               └── service
│   │   │                   ├── AccountService.java
│   │   │                   └── impl
│   │   │                       └── AccountServiceImpl.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.properties
│   │       ├── static
│   │       └── templates
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── forhadmethun
│                   └── banking
│                       └── service
│                           └── impl
│                               └── AccountServiceImplTest.java
```

AccountController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/account")
public class AccountController {
    @Autowired private AccountService accountService;
    @RequestMapping("/create")
    public List<Account> create(@RequestBody Account account) {
        accountService.save(account);
        return accountService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/all")
    public List<Account> all() {
        return accountService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/sendmoney")
    public Response sendMoney(
            @RequestBody TransferBalanceRequest transferBalanceRequest
            ) {

        return Response.ok().setPayload(
                accountService.sendMoney(
                        transferBalanceRequest
                )
        );
    }
    @RequestMapping("/statement")
    public Response getStatement(
            @RequestBody AccountStatementRequest accountStatementRequest

    ){
        return Response.ok().setPayload(
                accountService.getStatement(accountStatementRequest.getAccountNumber())
        );

    }

}
```

AccountStatementRequest.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AccountStatementRequest {
    private String accountNumber;

}
```

TransferBalanceRequest.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TransferBalanceRequest {
    private String fromAccountNumber;

    private String toAccountNumber;

    private BigDecimal amount;

}
```

AccountStatement.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class AccountStatement {
    BigDecimal currentBalance;
    List<Transaction> transactionHistory;
}
```

Response.java

```
package com.forhadmethun.banking.dto.response;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

import java.util.Date;


@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response<T> {

    private Status status;
    private T payload;
    private Object errors;
    private Object metadata;

    public static <T> Response<T> badRequest() {
        Response<T> response = new Response<>();
        response.setStatus(Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        return response;
    }

    public static <T> Response<T> ok() {
        Response<T> response = new Response<>();
        response.setStatus(Status.OK);
        return response;
    }

    public static <T> Response<T> unauthorized() {
        Response<T> response = new Response<>();
        response.setStatus(Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
        return response;
    }

    public static <T> Response<T> validationException() {
        Response<T> response = new Response<>();
        response.setStatus(Status.VALIDATION_EXCEPTION);
        return response;
    }

    public static <T> Response<T> wrongCredentials() {
        Response<T> response = new Response<>();
        response.setStatus(Status.WRONG_CREDENTIALS);
        return response;
    }

    public static <T> Response<T> accessDenied() {
        Response<T> response = new Response<>();
        response.setStatus(Status.ACCESS_DENIED);
        return response;
    }

    public static <T> Response<T> exception() {
        Response<T> response = new Response<>();
        response.setStatus(Status.EXCEPTION);
        return response;
    }

    public static <T> Response<T> notFound() {
        Response<T> response = new Response<>();
        response.setStatus(Status.NOT_FOUND);
        return response;
    }

    public static <T> Response<T> duplicateEntity() {
        Response<T> response = new Response<>();
        response.setStatus(Status.DUPLICATE_ENTITY);
        return response;
    }

    public void addErrorMsgToResponse(String errorMsg, Exception ex) {
        ResponseError error = new ResponseError()
                .setDetails(errorMsg)
                .setMessage(ex.getMessage())
                .setTimestamp(new Date());
        setErrors(error);
    }

    public enum Status {
        OK, BAD_REQUEST, UNAUTHORIZED, VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, EXCEPTION, WRONG_CREDENTIALS, ACCESS_DENIED, NOT_FOUND, DUPLICATE_ENTITY
    }

    @Getter
    @Accessors(chain = true)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class PageMetadata {
        private int size;
        private long totalElements;
        private int totalPages;
        private int number;

        public PageMetadata(int size, long totalElements, int totalPages, int number) {
            this.size = size;
            this.totalElements = totalElements;
            this.totalPages = totalPages;
            this.number = number;
        }
    }

}
```

ResponseError.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResponseError {
    private Date timestamp;
    private String message;
    private String details;
}
```

Account.java

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long accountId;

    String accountNumber;

    BigDecimal currentBalance;

}
```

Transaction.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long transactionId;

    private String accountNumber;

    private BigDecimal transactionAmount;

    private Timestamp transactionDateTime;

}
```

AccountRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
    Account findByAccountNumberEquals(String accountNumber);

}
```

TransactionRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Long> {
    List<Transaction> findByAccountNumberEquals(String accountNumber);

}
```

AccountService.java

```
public interface AccountService {
    List<Account> findAll();
    Account save(Account account);
    Transaction sendMoney(
            TransferBalanceRequest transferBalanceRequest
    );
    AccountStatement getStatement(String accountNumber);
}
```

AccountServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

    public Account save(Account account){
        accountRepository.save(account);
        return accountRepository.findByAccountNumberEquals(account.getAccountNumber());
    }

    public List<Account> findAll(){
        return accountRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Account findByAccountNumber(String accountNumber){
        Account account = accountRepository.findByAccountNumberEquals(accountNumber);
        return account;
    }


    @Override
    public Transaction sendMoney(
            TransferBalanceRequest transferBalanceRequest
    ) {
        String fromAccountNumber = transferBalanceRequest.getFromAccountNumber();
        String toAccountNumber = transferBalanceRequest.getToAccountNumber();
        BigDecimal amount = transferBalanceRequest.getAmount();
        Account fromAccount = accountRepository.findByAccountNumberEquals(
                fromAccountNumber
        );
        Account toAccount = accountRepository.findByAccountNumberEquals(toAccountNumber);
        if(fromAccount.getCurrentBalance().compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 1
                && fromAccount.getCurrentBalance().compareTo(amount) == 1
        ){
            fromAccount.setCurrentBalance(fromAccount.getCurrentBalance().subtract(amount));
            accountRepository.save(fromAccount);
            toAccount.setCurrentBalance(toAccount.getCurrentBalance().add(amount));
            accountRepository.save(toAccount);
            Transaction transaction = transactionRepository.save(new Transaction(0L,fromAccountNumber,amount,new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())));
            return transaction;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public AccountStatement getStatement(String accountNumber) {
        Account account = accountRepository.findByAccountNumberEquals(accountNumber);
        return new AccountStatement(account.getCurrentBalance(),transactionRepository.findByAccountNumberEquals(accountNumber));
    }
```

AccountServiceImplTest.java

````
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class AccountServiceImplTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class AccountServiceTestContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public AccountServiceImpl accountServiceImplTest() {
            return new AccountServiceImpl();

        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private AccountServiceImpl accountService;

    @Test
    public void sendMoneyTest() {
        Account account1 = new Account(0L, "1001", new BigDecimal(50000));
        Account account2 = new Account(0L, "2002", new BigDecimal(2000));
        accountService.save(account1);
        accountService.save(account2);

        TransferBalanceRequest transferBalanceRequest =
                new TransferBalanceRequest(
                        account1.getAccountNumber(),
                        account2.getAccountNumber(),
                        new BigDecimal(3000)
                );
        accountService.sendMoney(transferBalanceRequest);
        assertThat(accountService.findByAccountNumber(account1.getAccountNumber())
                .getCurrentBalance())
                .isEqualTo(new BigDecimal(47000));
        assertThat(accountService.findByAccountNumber(account2.getAccountNumber())
                .getCurrentBalance())
                .isEqualTo(new BigDecimal(5000));

    }

    @Test
    public void getStatement() {
        Account account1 = new Account(0L, "1001", new BigDecimal(50000));
        Account account2 = new Account(0L, "2002", new BigDecimal(2000));
        accountService.save(account1);
        accountService.save(account2);
        TransferBalanceRequest transferBalanceRequest =
                new TransferBalanceRequest(
                        account1.getAccountNumber(),
                        account2.getAccountNumber(),
                        new BigDecimal(3000)
                );

        accountService.sendMoney(transferBalanceRequest);
        assertThat(accountService.getStatement(account1.getAccountNumber())
                .getCurrentBalance())
                .isEqualTo(new BigDecimal(47000));
        accountService.sendMoney(transferBalanceRequest);
        assertThat(accountService.getStatement(account1.getAccountNumber())
                .getCurrentBalance()).isEqualTo(new BigDecimal(44000));
        assertThat(accountService.getStatement(account1.getAccountNumber())
                .getTransactionHistory().size()).isEqualTo(2);
    }

}
```
````

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is good. I would suggest following points to improve:

- Use `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping` and the others instead of `@RequestMapping`. It gives the other developers clear description of what method is used.
- It would be nice to add media types (`consumes="..."`, `produces="..."`)
- I would make `AccountController.accountService` field `final` and add as constructor param. It shows that `AccountController` can't exists without `AccountService`. In other words you don't have a way create a inconsistent instance of AccountService (in application context or tests).
- Do not return all accounts on account creation (`AccountController`). Usually we return new account with filled ID.
- Use generics in Response<...>
- I think you could use `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity` instead of your `Response`
- If `AccountStatementRequest` can't exists without `accountNumber` make the field final. (the same for `TransferBalanceRequest` and `AccountStatement`)
- It would be nice to annotate `AccountServiceImpl` (or it`s methods at leaset`sendMoney`)`@Transactional`. It should be done in single transaction I guess.
- I would move `dto.response` classes to `controller.response` and `dto.model` to `dto`

Comment: many many thanks for the suggestions ^_^ :)